# Deshabilitar botón después de realizar submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Tengo dos botones dentro de un `form` y me gustaría deshabilitar uno después de presionar otro y después de que realice el `submit` del `form`.

He intentado con esto:

```html
    <button type="submit" name="start" onclick="this.disabled=true">Start</button>
    <button type="submit" name="end" onclick="this.disabled=true">End</button>
```

Esto solo me deshabilita el botón al que haga click, pero ni me deshabilita el otro ni hace el `submit`.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con jQuery lo conseguirías de la siguiente manera. Alterna el estado de los botones y evita la propagación del evento del envío del formulario para evitar recargar la página.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#start, #end").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("disabled"))
    $(this).siblings().prop("disabled", !$(this).siblings().prop("disabled"))
    // Aquí incluyes el ajax y recoges los datos para enviar el formulario
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="miFormulario">
  <button type="submit" id="start" name="start">Start</button>
  <button type="submit" id="end" name="end" disabled>End</button>
</form>

<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Eso está genial, pero mi idea es que cuando se pulse el botón de `start`, se desactive `start` y se active `end` y al revés

Comment: Ahora el código está actualizado para que se alternen los disabled de los botones

Answer (score 1):

Es mejor que hagas una función javascript la cual contenga la logica y llamarla desde el onclick.

```
<form id="miFormulario">
    <button type="submit" id="start" name="start" onclick="miFuncion()">Start</button>
    <button type="submit" id="end" name="end" onclick="miFuncion()">End</button>
</form>

<script>
    function miFuncion() {
        document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("end").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("miFormulario").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme. Hace el `submit` pero cuando pulso el botón `start` no deshabilita el botón `end`.

Comment: Cuando haces un submit de un formulario la pagina se actualiza, por lo cual los botones vuelven a estar en su estado original. Pero en el momento de darle a cualquiera de los dos botones se deshabilitan los dos. Puedes comprobarlo quitando la linea de la funcion que hace el submit, para que compruebes como en efecto ambos se deshabilitan hasta que se manda el formulario.

Comment: ¿Y como podría hacerlo sin que se actualice la página? Que haga el submit pero no se actualice y así se vea el efecto

Comment: SI lo que quieres es mandar un formulario sin actualizar la pagina, busca tutoriales de AJAX.

Comment: Claro, es que estoy probando lo que me has dicho de comentar la línea de javascript que envía el formulario pero aún así me sigue recargando la página

Comment: Los botones de tipo submit envían el formulario por defecto. Deberías detener la propagación del evento. Con jQuery, puedes pasar el evento y hacer `event.preventDefault()` para evitar que el formulario se mandara